# Counterexample of Sobolev Embedding Theorem in $W_0^{1,p}$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

I am looking for a counterexample of Sobolev Embedding Theorem, i.e. I am seeking for a sobolev function $u\in W_0^{1,p}(\Omega),\,p\in[1,n)$, $\Omega$ is a bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that the inequality: $||u||_{L^q}\leq C||\nabla u||_{L^p}$ does **not** hold, where $q>p^*:=\frac{np}{n-p}$. A similar question was asked in the past, but with  $\mathbb{R}^n$ as a domain and the space used was $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$, see [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/243733/counterexample-of-sobolev-embedding-theorem)

Comment: You can use the exact same example in that question (suppose $0\in \Omega$), just use a mollifier to cut if off from $\Omega$, the singularity is near $0$.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any special function to reach this conclusion.

Any domain contains a ball; so it's enough to consider a ball, which may as well be centered at $0$. Take any function $f$ with nonzero $L^q$ norm supported in this ball. Consider the sequence $f_k(x)=f(kx)$ and use the change of variables $y=kx$ to show that 
$$
\|f_k\|_{L^q} = k^{-n/q} \|f\|_{L^q},\quad \|\nabla f_k\|_{L^p} = k^{1-n/p} \|f\|_{L^p}
$$ 
The conclusion follows since $-\frac{n}{q} > 1-\frac{n}{p}$.

Comment: Thanks, @Sally! This really helps! Shouldn't it be $\|f_k\|_{L^q} = k^{-n/q} \|f\|_{L^q},\quad \|\nabla f_k\|_{L^p} = k^{1-n/p} \|f\|_{L^p}$
(And the conclusion follows since $-\frac{n}{q} >1 -\frac{n}{p}$)?

Comment: Yes, I corrected this.

Comment: Thanks again, @Sally. One more question - why is it necessary to work in a ball? Can't I just take a function $f\in\Omega$ with the same procedure?

Comment: If $\Omega$ is not star-shaped about $0$, the support of the function $f(kx)$ might fall outside of the domain.