# Limit cases in sobolev embedding

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

I am trying to find coumterexamples for the critic cases in sobolev embedding theorem for all $\mathbb{R}^N$. For instance, a function $u\in W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^N)$ s.t. $u\notin L^q(\mathbb{R}^N)$ for $q>Np/(N-p)$. This is the case of $1<p<N$. Can anyone give me an idea or hint of how to do it for the other two cases $p=N$ and $p>N$. I am really stucked.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The only limiting case is $p=N$. This is a possible duplicate of [Counterexample of Sobolev Embedding Theorem?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/243733/counterexample-of-sobolev-embedding-theorem)

Comment: No, the limit cases are considered in $q$ not in $p$.

Comment: If $p > N$ there is no limit for $q$. The embedding is completely continuous into a suitable Hoelder space. If $p <N$, my answer in the quoted post tells you how to find a counterexample for $q = Np/(N-p)$. If $p = N$, the embedding is into any $L^q$ with $q < \infty$ but not into $L^\infty$.

Comment: That is true, I was confused. Thanks. By the way, how can be computed the norm $\Vert \nabla u\Vert _{W^{1,p}}$ where $u=\Vert x\Vert^{-\alpha}$?

Comment: It's in the answer. Use polar coordinates.

Comment: Yes, but I dont know how to do it. I keep trying meanwhile

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91520/discussion-between-r-n-marley-and-hans-engler).